# Переопределение стандартного widget в Django forms

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Необходимо переопределить стандартный виджет для формы. Использую следующее:

- Django 1.11
- Django-material 1.1.1

Пытаюсь переопределить шаблон для виджета:

- forms.py

  ```
  from django.forms import widgets

  class NewCheckboxInput(widgets.CheckboxInput):
      template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/checkbox.html'
  ```
- Создал новый шаблон по пути

  ```
  ├── templates  
  │   ├── django  
  │   │   └── forms  
  │   │       └── widgets  
  │   │           └── checkbox.html
  ```
- checkbox.html

  ```
  <input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}" test='test' /><a href='ya.ru'>Some text</a>
  ```
- Согласно [статье](https://timonweb.com/tutorials/overriding-field-widgets-in-django-doesnt-work-template-not-found-the-solution/) дописал настройки в settings.py

  ```
  INSTALLED_APPS = [
      ...
      # django forms
      'django.forms',
      ...
  ]

  FORM_RENDERER = 'django.forms.renderers.TemplatesSetting'
  ```

Но это не срабатывает. Как это починить?